# Python 2.7: Save all exceptions into database (convert to unicode Problems)

Tags: database, python-2.7, unicode, sqlite, exception

I am trying to save all exceptions thrown by a python service (running hidden on Windows 7/10) into a sqlite3 database file. In addition to other things(traceback, date, etc) I want to save the error message too.

My Problem is that there are some error messages that I cannot convert to unicode (Especially some WindowsErrors and errors with a german 'Umlaut': ä, ö, ü). As I don't know every possible error in advance **I want to have a function that can handle ALL errors and convert their message to unicode**.

Can someone tell me what the **convertToUnicode**-function has to look like?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def someErrorneousFunction():
    raise RuntimeError('Not a unicode string. But with a german Umlaut: ä!')

def saveExceptionToDBThatOnlyAcceptsUnicode(msg):
    """SQL INSERT SOME STUFF... + THE UNICODE ERROR MESSAGE!"""
    pass

def convertToUnicode(e):
    """ What to do here ??? """
    pass

try:
    someErrorneousFunction()
except Exception as e:
    unicode_error_msg = convertToUnicode(e)
    saveExceptionToDBThatOnlyAcceptsUnicode(unicode_error_msg)
```

**Note:** I found that some Exceptions have an attribute called **.msg** or **.str**, but not all of them!

Does this method make sense at all? I know its bad practice to catch ALL exceptions with no distinction but as my software occasionally is in testmode somewhere else and I want to get the exception database per mail it seemed meaningful to me. Furthermore I distinguish the errors I know from those I don't know in advance.

I would appreciate any advise!

Thank you!

Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as your demo shows, the source file is known to be in UTF-8, then this should work:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import traceback

def someErrorneousFunction():
    raise RuntimeError('Not a unicode string. But with a german Umlaut: ä!')

def saveExceptionToDBThatOnlyAcceptsUnicode(msg):
    print type(msg)
    print msg

def convertToUnicode(e):
    return traceback.format_exc(e).decode('utf8')

try:
    someErrorneousFunction()
except Exception as e:
    unicode_error_msg = convertToUnicode(e)
    saveExceptionToDBThatOnlyAcceptsUnicode(unicode_error_msg)
```

Output:

```
<type 'unicode'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 15, in <module>
    someErrorneousFunction()
  File "C:\test.py", line 5, in someErrorneousFunction
    raise RuntimeError('Not a unicode string. But with a german Umlaut: ä!')
RuntimeError: Not a unicode string. But with a german Umlaut: ä!
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked for me!